# Object to Csv conversion

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, csv, object

in javascript (Angular)

trying to convert an array of objects into a csv file

the objects are like

```
{name:ab, phone:231}
{name:alex,email:alex@gmail.com}
{name: john, phone: 342, email: j@j.io}
```

how to convert this object to csv so that im not losing any of the fields

Comment: These aren't valid objects.

Comment: you can use this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

Answer (score 1):

You habe to create an array of keys to guarantee key order, then map that to the values and join them by a comma:

```
 ["name", "phone", "email"].map(k => obj[k]).join(",")
```